# Excel VBA Internet Explorer Onclick to click drop down menu

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, onclick

I am attempting to click a drop down type menu in Internet Explorer using Excel VBA code.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="treeNodeStyle" id="trMenu_14" nowrap="" style="visibility: visible;">
<div class="treeNodeWrapperStyle" nowrap="">
<a class="treeInlineStyle" onclick="FolderExpand('trMenu','14');return false;" href="">
<img align="top" class="treeInlineStyle" src="/visimages/tree/plus.gif" border="0">
</a> 
<div class="treeSelectorStyle" onclick="selectNode('trMenu','14',false)" ondblclick="dblselectNode('trMenu','14')">
<img align="absmiddle" class="treeInlineStyleImg" src="/visimages/tree/folder.gif" border="0">
<div title="Finance" class="treeNodeTextStyle" nowrap="true"> Finance</div>
```

Here is the VBA code I am attempting to use. Trying to understand if I should be referencing the ID or the class.

```
Dim btn as Object

For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("treeNodeStyle")
    If btn.innerText = "Finance" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next btn
```

I cannot get the code to find any kind of element within the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you want to expand the folder but it would help to indicate which element needs to receive the click.

To do this I use a css attribute = value selector with * contains operator to target the onclick attribute by the part of its value

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick*=FolderExpand]").click
```

If the event needs triggering then

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick*=FolderExpand]").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Similar principles can be applied to target the other elements which have `onclick` or `ondblclick` attributes.

The finance element can be targeted by its title attribute

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title=Finance]")
```

I'm not sure this is a target for a click however.

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML code it looks like **Finance** div is inside a parent div which has class name as **treeSelectorStyle** and it has the onclick event.

So you can try to click on parent div using its class name may help to solve the issue.

Sample code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\152.html"   'chnage the URL here...
    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    IE.document.getelementsbyclassname("treeSelectorStyle").Item(0).Click
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here based on sample code I click on Item(0) but you need to change the index number of element which has **treeSelectorStyle** class to click the correct element.